# mf4 to csv conversion in python

Tags: python, csv, dataset, asammdf

I have a dataset of mf4 and I want to convert it into CSV in python. I have read the data from mf4 and convert it into csv (as given below) but I am getting an error, as I am new to python, so unable to find an appropriate method to convert.

```
from asammdf import MDF
import pandas as pd

efficient = MDF('./Data.mf4')

df = efficient.to_csv()


df.append(efficient)

mdf.save('output.csv')
```

I am getting this error:

```
MdfException: "Data.mf4" is not a valid ASAM MDF file: magic header is b'timestam'
```

Kindly suggest. Thank you!

Comment: @jar Please update more information for this post. This will help you avoid being voted.

Comment: Thanks, I have added more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have mf4 file. Is this file converted from an mdf file?
If it is as I thought, you should use the mdf file to convert it into a CSV file. Here it is anyway and hopefully you or someone else can come up with a better method.

```
import mdfreader
import os

extension = [".mdf"]   
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input_path):
    for file in files:
        ext = os.path.splitext(file)[-1].lower()
        f_name = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
        if ext in extension:
            yop=mdfreader.Mdf(os.path.join(root, file))
            yop=mdfreader.Mdf(os.path.join(root, file), channel_list=['channel1', 'channel2'], convert_after_read=False)
            yop=mdfreader.Mdf(os.path.join(root, file), compression=True)
            yop=mdfreader.Mdf(os.path.join(root, file), no_data_loading=True)
            yop=mdfreader.Mdf(os.path.join(root, file), metadata=0)  
            yop.get_channel_name4('channelName', 'source path or name')
            yop.get_channel('channelName')
            yop.get_channel_data('channelName')
            yop.MDFVersionNumber
            info=mdfreader.MdfInfo()
            info.list_channels('NameOfFile') 
            info.read_info('NameOfFile') 
            yop.info 
            yop.keys()
            yop.masterChannelList
            yop.plot(['channel1',['channel2','channel3']])
            yop.resample(0.1)
            yop.resample(master_channel='master3')
            yop.cut(begin=10, end=15)
            yop.export_to_csv(sampling=0.01)
            yop.export_to_NetCDF()
            yop.export_to_hdf5()
            yop.export_to_matlab()
            yop.export_to_xlsx()
            yop.export_to_parquet()
            yop.return_pandas_dataframe('master_channel_name')
            yop.convert_to_pandas()
            yop.keep_channels({'channel1','channel2','channel3'})
            yop2=mdfreader.Mdf('NameOfFile_2')
            yop.merge_mdf(yop2)
            yop.write('NewNameOfFile')
            yop.write4('NameOfFile', compression=True)
            yop.write3()
            yop.attachments
```

I used lib mdfreader to do this. You can refer below link for more detail.

[mdfreader](https://pypi.org/project/mdfreader/)

Thanks for your feedback. I got it your issue, you can try:

```
pip install https://github.com/danielhrisca/asammdf/archive/development.zip -I --no-deps
```

to install the development branch code and then

```
mdf = MDF('file.mf4')
mdf.export('csv', 'export.csv', single_time_base=True, raster=0.1)
```

About your case (use anaconda). Please try:

```
conda install https://github.com/danielhrisca/asammdf/archive/development.zip -I --no-deps
```

Lib mdfreader. In you want to install it.

```
conda install mdfreader
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. No, this file is not converted from MDF, I already have data in mf4 format and also I am using anaconda which is not supporting mdfreader. Do you have any other suggestions to solve this problem please?

Comment: @Thuan, Thank you so much, it worked with API usage :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `asammdf` package, either by using the API or the GUI.

Install the package and the GUI dependencies:

```
pip install asammdf[gui]
```

### API usage

```
from asammdf import MDF
mdf = MDF('input.mf4')
mdf.export(fmt='csv', filename='output.csv')
```

There are other export options that you can use, please check the documentation [https://asammdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#asammdf.mdf.MDF.export](http://MDF.export%20documentation)

### GUI

Start the GUI from the `python_installation_folder\Scripts\asammdfgui.exe` or by running this script

```
from asammdf.gui.asammdfgui import main
main()
```

[image]

Comment: @daniel Thank you so much, it worked with API usage :)

Comment: @jar danielhrisca, he is developed this lid: https://github.com/danielhrisca/asammdf/archive/development.zip -I --no-deps. Really lucky :)

Comment: Yes I am the lead developer for the package including the GUI

Answer (score 2):

The ASAM MDF (Measurement Data Format) is a binary file format for recording e.g. CAN, CAN FD, and LIN bus data. Today, the MDF format is the industry standard - ensuring interoperability across many CAN tools.

The CANedge supports the latest MF4 file format - and below we list benefits, basics, and software/API tools. We also provide sample MF4 data (J1939, OBD2).

```
from asammdf import MDF, Signal #import asammdf
f_in = input ("Enter Input MDF4 FIle :") 
mdf = MDF(f_in) #read mf4 data
f_out = f_in.replace(".MF4", ".csv")
mdf.export(fmt='csv', filename= f_out) #write to csv
```

MDF4 files are comprised of "blocks" - most of which are in practice arbitrarily ordered. Via a system of internal "links", these blocks form a hierarchy.

This structure enables more flexible log files vs. e.g. CSV - ideal for e.g. mixing CAN, CAN FD & LIN, or supporting both raw/physical data.
[image]

Source: https://www.csselectronics.com/pages/mf4-mdf4-measurement-data-format